# Mostrar valores de un HashMap

Tags: java

Estoy intentado sacar lo valores de un hashmap, en este caso un objeto Juez.

He hecho esto:

```java
private void buscarJuez() {
    String numLicencia = this.jTextFieldBuscarJuez.getText();
    if (Jueces.containsKey(numLicencia)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, numLicencia + ": " + Jueces.values(), "Informacion", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);  
    }
}
```

Añadir Juez

```
 private void anadirJuez() {
        //Exigimos que todos los campos deben estar con datos si no no se guardará
        if (this.jTextFieldLicencia.getText().equals("")
                || this.jTextFieldNombreJuez.getText().equals("")
                || this.jTextFieldFecha.getText().equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this.jDialogAñadirJuez, "Debe rellenar todos los campos.", "Alta de libro fallida", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        } else {
            //tranformación de String  a integer
            String cadena = jTextFieldFecha.getText();
            String[] camposFecha = cadena.split("/");

            int dia = Integer.parseInt(camposFecha[0]);
            int mes = Integer.parseInt(camposFecha[1]);
            int anio = Integer.parseInt(camposFecha[2]);
            Calendar fecha = new GregorianCalendar();
            fecha.set(anio,mes,dia);
            fecha.getTime();

            String numLicencia = jTextFieldLicencia.getText();
            String nombre = jTextFieldNombreJuez.getText();
            Juez juez1 = new Juez(nombre, fecha);
            Jueces.put(numLicencia, juez1);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this.jDialogAñadirJuez, "El Juez se ha agregado correctamente.", "Alta Juez", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }

    }
```

La busqueda me la hace bien, pero no me muestra los valores, cuando busco, me printa esto:

> AAA-111:[Juez{numLicencia=null}]

No se ahora mismo que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Quizá no tenga nada que ver pero... en el `if` pones todos los campos con `this.`, pero en el `else` lo haces sin `this.`. ¿Eso te funciona bien?

Comment: Lo primero que deberías hacer es aclarar qué esperas ver... y ya puestos, poner el código de tu método *toString*. Porque en ningún momento parece que asignes un número de licencia a tu juez...

Answer (score 2):

Tendrás que usar la clave para acceder al valor que quieres, no?

Sería `Jueces.get(numLicencia)`

O sea, en la línea donde muestras prueba con:

```java
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, numLicencia + ": " + Jueces.get(numLicencia), "Informacion", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Con `values()` lo que haces es sacar todos los valores del `HashMap`, no los del juez que buscas.

Comment: Nada, me pasa lo mismo, igual estoy haciendo algo mal cuando introduzco los datos